# SSH Tunnel with R error: Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (115)

Tags: mysql, r, shiny, ssh-tunnel, rmysql

I am attempting to connect to a remote database that requires SSH keys. I am running the [Shiny Server](https://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/download-server/) on Ubuntu 20. The following snippet works from the R interpreter, but fails when in my Shiny app.

```
library(RMySQL)
library(callr)

setwd('/folder/to/pemfile')

rs <- r_session$new(wait = TRUE, wait_timeout = 3500)

rs$call(function(){
  session <- ssh::ssh_connect("<user-name>@<ip-address>", keyfile = "myfile.pem", verbose = FALSE)

  ssh::ssh_tunnel(session, port=3307, target="127.0.0.1:3306")
})

conn <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user='<db-user>', password='<db-password>', dbname='<db-name>', port=3307, host='127.0.0.1')


query <- "<insert-query-here>"    
result <- dbSendQuery(conn, query)
data_df <- fetch(result, n = -1)

# Close Remote Session.
rs$close()

setwd('/path/to/original/folder')
```

The error message that I receive from the Shiny app is

```
    Error in .local(drv, ...) : 
  Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (115)
Calls: runApp ... ..stacktraceon.. -> dbConnect -> dbConnect -> .local
Execution halted
```

From other posts I have tried changing the MySQL server bind address to 0.0.0.0 from 127.0.0.1, but the same error is returned. Additionally, I tried using localhost instead of 127.0.0.1, but that fails for both the interpreter and in the Shiny App with an Access Denied error. I am leaning towards this being an issue with the Shiny installation given it works from the R terminal when run line by line.

MySQL version running on the Ubuntu machine

```
mysql  Ver 8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

R Package Version

```
> packageVersion('RMySQL')
[1] ‘0.10.22’
> packageVersion('callr')
[1] ‘3.7.0’
>
> packageVersion('shiny')
[1] ‘1.7.1’
>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I would call this a "fix", but the Shiny app works *after* I did the following.

```
Sys.sleep(1) # <- Added this line before the line below
conn <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user='<db-user>', password='<db-password>', dbname='<db-name>', port=3307, host='127.0.0.1')
```

I came to this solution by running the Shiny app from the browser, and copying/pasting into the R interpreter, both with failure.

However, when I copied/pasted the code into the terminal, then ran the connection line manually, it worked as expected so I added a sleep line and it worked.

If anyone has additional explanation, I'd be very curious.

EDIT: I have come to the conclusion, that the reason for the error is because ssh_tunnel does not have enough time to make the connection before running dbConnect().